# Работа цикла (сопрограммы) в выключенной игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

Игра, в ней есть `int` переменая `score` и сопрограмма, в ней цикл `while` который увеличивает `score` на `1` каждую секунду.

Как реальзовать, чтобы в выключенной игре увеличивалось `score`. Чтобы я запустил игру допустим через час и `score` выросло на нужное количество.

Какими способами такое реализуют в играх? И где про это почитать?

Comment: Запомнить дату начала отсчета score. в любой момент времени вы сможете вычислить разницу в секундах между началом и текущим, что и даст вам нужную величину. Всегда ваш, Кэп )

Comment: @morphey83, оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ. Очень даже правильно работающий вариант.

Comment: @morphey83 можешь пример кода показать

Comment: А если персонажу по какой-то причине перестали капать очки?

Comment: Что тут показывать? Как вычесть две даты? `((TimeSpan)(d1 - d2)).TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 2):

Можно запомнить дату начала отсчета score. В любой момент времени вы сможете вычислить разницу в секундах между началом и текущим моментом, что и даст вам нужную величину.

P.S.

> А если персонажу по какой-то причине перестали капать очки?

Имея полную величину вы всегда сможете реализовать любую логику в подсчетах score.
Но есть нюансы: сдвинув системную дату можно "случайно" выиграть )) но это уже совсем другая история ...

Comment: Только есть одна проблема. Умный юзер может вырубить инет, и перемотать время, если игра не онлайн

Comment: @SeeSharp, я не знаток проектирования игр, но, думаю, речь идет скорее о учебном примере, нежели о реальном проекте. Скорее всего реальный проект защитился бы от такого "мошенничества" путем проверки соединения + шифрованного канала + серверного учета. Ваше сомнение вполне уместно, но уже было отражено в моем ответе.

Comment: Да, вроде бы, достаточно хранить и использовать время сервера, а не клиента, чтобы избежать такой проблемы.

Comment: @SeeSharp, так можно спрашивать время у сервера, а не у смартфона пользователя :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вот, другое дело)